# Which UWP controls are supported as XAML Islands in a Desktop application?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp

I'm playing with UWP in plain Win32 projects, reading more about C++/WinRT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started), the [XamlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader?view=netframework-4.7.2), the [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events) and the [control collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls).

For this I 've made a [small library](https://github.com/WindowsNT/uwplib) which enscapulates such a control into a plain HWND and I can set the text using WM_SETTEXT.

Is there documentation on which of these controls are available in plain Win32 and which arent?

For example, this markup works:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="10">
  <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Hover to Click"
          Click="OnClick1" ClickMode="Hover"
          Margin="5" Width="150"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Foreground="Green"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Margin="5,8,0,0" />

  <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Press to Click"
          Click="OnClick2" ClickMode="Press"
          Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="150" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Foreground="Blue"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="text2" Margin="5,8,0,0" />

  <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="Reset"
          Click="OnClick3" ClickMode="Release"
          Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="150"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="text3" Margin="5,8,0,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Generally, many controls work. However some, like [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview), don't:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
```

When using `XamlReader::Load` to load this, it throws {value=0x802b000a }   winrt::hresult E_XAMLPARSEFAILED:XAML parsing failed.

Do I miss something? Are there some controls not yet available? Do I need some additional dependency?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. UWP controls are language independent so they are supported in UWP C++ apps the same way they are supported in UWP C# apps. Maybe you are asking: "what UWP controls are supported in Win32 apps via XAML Islands" ? Please clarify

Comment: Yes, this is about using them in plain Win32, so Xaml Islands. `Is there documentation on which of these controls are available in plain Win32 and which arent?`

Comment: @ste It seems that UWP controls can only be used independent of their implementation language in UWP apps. Some controls (like the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/)) are not available to native code. At least that's how I read [Host UWP XAML controls in desktop apps (XAML Islands)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, that's what I was saying in my comment :-) - all UWP controls are supported in C++ UWP apps the same way they are supported in C# UWP apps. The original question was asking which controls are supported in C++. Now the title has been updated and it's more clear what the question is. Btw, the XAML Island limitation is not really about native vs managed (or C++ vs C#), it's about Win32 app model vs UWP app model.